# How to follow the redirct and test again in test script

Tags: python, django

I have this test script for uploading file

```
    with open('_material/content.xlsx','rb') as fp:
        response = self.client.login(username="user@example.com", password="qwpo1209")

        response = self.client.post('/cms/content/up',
        {'name': 'test', 'content_file': fp,"is_all":"True"})
    
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code,302) # it shows ok
        
        #then next, how can I follow the redirect and test the page??
        self.assertContains(response, "success!")
```

It returns the redirect 302 but I want to follow the redirect and nect check.

Because there comes the message such as `success!`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `follow=True` to follow the redirect in a [**`.post(…)`** call <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.post), so:

```
response = self.client.post(
    '/cms/content/up',
    {'name': 'test', 'content_file': fp, 'is_all': 'True'},
    follow=True
)
```

as is specified in the documentation:

> If you set follow to `True` the client will follow any redirects and a `redirect_chain` attribute will be set in the response object containing tuples of the intermediate urls and status codes.

Comment: It works perfect for me. I can choose just checking 302 or follow the link with this flag. Thank you very much.